# How to work with SOAP that has authentication in iOS

Tags: ios, authentication, soap

I have a SOAP web service with authentication key.

This is the request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <FlightSearch xmlns="http://someurl.com/">
      <Authkey>string</Authkey>
      <from>string</from>
      <SesID>string</SesID>
    </FlightSearch>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <FlightSearchResponse xmlns="http://someurl.com/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

help me with this to consume data from this. thank